# ¿Cómo verificar las coincidencias?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo instancias de un constructor así:

```
function C() {
  this.age = null;
  this.personas = 0;
};

for(var i =0;i<10;i++) {
  var b = new C();

  b.age = i * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)+1);
  b.personas++;

  console.log("Existen: " +b.personas + " personas..");
}
```

Lo que quiero lograr es contar las **DIFERENTES** cantidades de edades, por ende si `Math.random` me genera una misma edad, esa edad se contará solo como una. **¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?** Llevo mucho tiempo intentándolo y sin introducir las edades en *arrays* por favor.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar mejor tu problema? ¿Eres consciente que `b.personas` siempre valdrá 1?

Comment: Con "sin introducir las edades en arrays por favor." ¿te refieres a sin ninguna estructura o mecanismo que permita recordar o almacenar los valores utilizados hasta el momento?

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar existe un error semantico en tu codigo, ya que en el `for` en cada iteracion estarias definiendo a la variable `b` como un objeto con el atributo `age` igual a `null` y `personas` igual a 0, claro despues a `age` le asignas un valor "aleatorio" y al atributo `personas` le sumas 1, pero el problema es que siempre estas trabajando sobre la variable `b`.

Entonces para lo que quieres hacer podrias definir un arreglo llamado `personas` al cual le colocaremos cada instancia creada en el loop `for`, de esta forma podremos accedder posteriormente a los objetos creados.

```
  function Persona(edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
  };

  function myFunction() {
    personas = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var persona = new Persona(i * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1));

      personas.push(persona);
    }

    console.log(personas);

    console.log(personas.length);
  };
```

Si ejecutamos este codigo obtendremos esto de salida:

[image: Consola]

Es decir, hasta este punto tenemos un arreglo con 10 objetos creados que tienen edades, ahora para contar el numero de personas con la misma edad podemos usar un [arreglo asociativo](https://www.xul.fr/javascript/associative.php) al momento de crear los objetos y asociarle a una llave que tendra como identificador la edad y un valor igual al numero de personas con esa edad.

```
  function Persona(edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
  };

  function myFunction() {
    var personas = [];

    var contador = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var persona = new Persona(i * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1));

      if (!contador.hasOwnProperty(persona.edad.toString()))
        contador[persona.edad.toString()] = 1;
      else
        contador[persona.edad.toString()]++;

      personas.push(persona);
    }

    console.log("Las personas creadas son: ");

    console.log(personas);

    console.log("El numero de personas son: ");

    console.log(personas.length);

    console.log("El numero de veces que se repiten las edades son: ");

    console.log(contador);
  };
```

Si ejecutas el codigo de arriba obtendras un resultado como el siguiente.

[image: Consola]

De esta forma puedes ver cuantas veces se repitieron las edades, el numero de personas creadas y las edades de cada persona.

Saludos.